# Weird probability question

Tags: probability

Sorry for the topic being weird, but as a person not too good at math I would like to know whether the following argument is mathematically valid:

> If $50$% of pregnancies are aborted, is it valid to say that a fetus has $50$% chance to be aborted? Considering that criteria for abortion is random.
>
> Is the following sentence that I heard, mathematically valid?
> "$50$% of pregnancies are aborted, therefore if you are a fetus you have $50$% chance of not coming out alive"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the only way for a fetus not to come out alive is by abortion, then yes, this statement is mathematically valid. As far as I know, there are many other circumstances under which a fetus may come out not alive, so the statement is not necessarily true.

Comment: Great explaination ! Does that mean that the real probability is even higher than 50%, since other possible circumstances only add the probability ?

Comment: Yes (unless, of course, a fetus may come out alive after an abortion, but I doubt that this is possible).

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: it just about follows, if 50% of pregnancies are aborted, then 50% of fetuses are aborted - except there are some rare cases of multiple pregnancies where only some of the fetuses are aborted, so you could say that it is perhaps slightly less than 50% of fetuses are aborted, even if an abortion is carried out in 50% of pregnancies.  This is in the same way that the average number of legs a person has is less than two (because vastly more people have 0 or 1 legs than have more than 2 legs) overall, it is 1.98 legs per person on average (for example)